# SVN/Tortoise SVN - can connect to repository, but not create folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm missing a step somewhere, I just don't know where.

I have SVN set up and running on a remote server (svn.mydomain.com/svn) and I can browse the repository from my local machine using repo-browser, but when I try to create a new directory or add a new file I get an "Authorization Failed!" message.

But I was never asked to input my credentials! I have a user/pass set up on the server in the passwd file, if I could just figure out how to supply those credentials from my local machine.

I've tried the trick of going into TortoiseSVN Settings/Saved Data/Authentication Data to clear the cache, but that button is grayed out, so apparently I have no stored authentication data to delete. So why isn't TortoiseSVN prompting me to supply credentials, instead of just throwing up an "Authorization Failed!" message?

Comment: UPDATE: I get the same error when I try to use the repo-browser on the remote server itself. This is making zero sense.

Comment: Is your URL properly cased? TortoiseSVN can allow a checkout with the incorrect case in the url but will fail when you try to commit.

Comment: How would I find that out? Where can I check the proper case of the URL?

Comment: I am not aware of any way other than asking your svn administrator.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your Subversion server [is configured to allow Single Sign-On authentication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) (for example Integrated Windows Authentication in Active Directory). In such case, it seems that your user account has Read Only access to the repository, therefore you should ask your repository maintainer to provide you with Read / Write privileges.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments of the question, you need to check the casing of your URL, for example svn.mydomain.com/svn vs svn.MyDomain.com/SVN.

To change your URL, you can right click in your working copy's folder, go to TortoiseSVN -> Relocate... and change the casing as required:

[image: relocate svn working copy]